# C# Selenium how to turn off google energy saving mode?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing a project with C# using selenium and I'm using many functions that Selenium provides. I'm developing using a laptop and when my laptop is low on battery, ChromDriver starts in energy saving mode and prevents some functions in my code from working. I definitely need to turn it off.

I did a lot of research but I couldn't find a source that shows me exactly how to turn off the 'energy saving' mode. ChatGPT gave me some suggestions but unfortunately it didn't work.

I used the following 2 codes individually, but unfortunately they don't help either.

```
//The 'ChromeOptions' class is the object and a 'ChromeDriver' object is retrieved using it.

options.AddArgument("--disable-features=ChromeEOLPowerSaveMode");
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion");
```

Please don't suggest me to turn off all extensions, there are some extensions I use in my project and I can't remove them from the project.